# Is there a way to speak "Send" in order to send an SMS?

Tags: sms, 4.2-jelly-bean, google-voice-actions

I know I can pull up my SMS app and press the microphone to activate speech. I speak my message, but then I need to press the "send" button to actually send my message.

Is there a way to activate the send function by saying a keyword instead of pressing the button?

Coming from an iPhone where Siri does most of this for me, basically I can say

> Tell my wife, I'm running a bit late.

Siri responds

> Here's your message to *wife's name*, would you like me to send your message?

I say

> Yes

and off it goes.

I'm looking for something similar in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Google Now/Voice Actions I don't think there's any way to do this. Some actions will happen automatically after a short delay ("note to self..." is one I know offhand; there may be others), but text messaging requires you to actually press the "Send" button on the card that pops up.

However, you could try a third-party app for these specific functions that you'd like to be completely hands-free. [Dragon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nuance.balerion) works a bit more closely to Siri, acting in a conversational manner, and will prompt you for a "Yes/No" to send a message in a very similar fashion. [Skyvi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bluetornadosf.smartypants) is another option you could try, which will send text messages automatically after a 5 second delay (during which time you can press a "Cancel" button to stop the sending).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Dragon looks awesome, but is blocked in Canada. I tried Skyvi (briefly) yesterday, and didn't really like it... I'll give it another go.

Comment: Running Dragon seems to be the best. There are a lot of drawbacks, but It'll do for now.